# how can I get multiple query responses in php?

Tags: php, android, database, kotlin, android-volley

Hello everyone and thanks for reading.
I'm using php to receive some queries in an android app, but I only know how to receive only one object from an array, I don't know how to receive the entire array. This is what I have done in my php document.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUUw7.png)

Comment: Use a loop..there are so many examples online already and in the PHP manual.

Comment: P.s. as per [ask] please never post pictures of your code, always post it as text. Thanks

Comment: You also are open to SQL injections with that code. Parameterize query and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are just getting the first result. You need to iterate over all results.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while (($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    // Do jour job with $res
}
```

Note: Also, I've changed mysqli_fetch_array with mysqli_fetch_assoc, as you only will treat $res as an associative array.

Answer (score -1):

In your case `$res` is array, so you need iterate over it to get acceess to rows from dtabase. For example:

```
$res = mysqli_fetch_array();
foreach($res as $row){
 $columnValue =  $row['columnName'];
}
```

So you need to do the same as presented in code sample as you need.